# Is there a portable ID3 tag editor for Windows?

Tags: windows, music, portable, id3

I've used Easytag in the past and found it perfect for my needs, but I don't believe it can run portably, for example from Dropbox. Is there a program that a) will let me edit ID3 tags of mp3 files, preferably multiple tags (for example from the same album), and b) runs from a single folder, without needing admin permissions or needing to install anything in the registry, system folders, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are happy with Easytag, and the only thing you miss is portability: there's **[Easytag portable](http://www.softpedia.com/get/PORTABLE-SOFTWARE/Multimedia/Audio/X-EasyTag.shtml)** available matching all your requirements perfectly. Enjoy!